# List item fade when navigating

Tags: javascript, jquery, list, navigation, fadein

I have a group of list items that I control through "Next" and "Prev" buttons. The code shows five list items at a time, if there are more you can click "Next" and you'll see another five - if you click "Prev" you'll see the previous five...pretty simple operation and it works. You can see a live example at: http://joshrodg.com/hallmark/events/.

The javascript I am using is:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $li = $('.eo-events li');
    $li.hide().filter(':lt(5)').show()
    var x = 5;

$('#next, #prev').click(function () {
    var m = this.id === 'prev' ? 'first' : 'last';
    var $m = $li.filter(':visible')[m]()[this.id + 'All'](":lt(" + x + ")");
    if ( $m.length == 0 ) return;
        $li.hide();
        $m.show();
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/479Fr/

What I'd like to do is have the items fade-in instead of just appearing...kind of like: https://codepo8.github.io/simple-carousel/carousel-pointer-events.html (or something similar)

I know there are some carousels out there that can do this, but I don't need something that bulky, especially since the functionality already works with such a small amount of code.

Is there a simple modification I can make to what I'm already using to accomplish something like this?

Thanks,
Josh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like that :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $li = $('#myList li');
    $li.hide().filter(':lt(5)').show()
    var x = 5;

    $('#next, #prev').click(function () {
        var m = this.id === 'prev' ? 'first' : 'last';
        var $m = $li.filter(':visible')[m]()[this.id + 'All'](":lt(" + x + ")");
        if ( $m.length == 0 ) return;   
        var time = 250;
        $li.fadeOut(time);
        setTimeout( function(){
            $m.fadeIn(time);
        }, time);

    });
});
```

Comment: This is a great solution, I knew it was simple, but everything I tried (before this solution) applied the effect to each individual list item not each set of five...thanks!

Comment: that will work, agree smart one. But in corner cases it can glitch by overlapping, as animation time is not guaranteed. Better to increase `time`  for e.g. `50`, to ensure animation will end to that time.

Comment: Not sure if you mean't add 50 (so 300) or change 250 to 50?

Answer (score 2):

Use the JQuery .fadein/out to have fading animations

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Comment: This should really be a comment, not an answer

Comment: that will not work. There showing/hiddings separate elements. It will blinking.

Comment: @AlexIvasyuv That's why they have wait till animation is complete properties.